# Combine two queries into one and sort them

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to display buildings and circuits in list (only 3 in total, sorted by the column "updated_at"). The problem is that they are not in the same table. I have a table `circuits` and a table `buildings`.

I tried to do this:

```
$buildings = Building::published()->limit(3)->get();
$circuits = Circuit::published()->limit(3)->get();

$merged = $buildings->merge($circuits);

$this->data['buildingsAndCircuits'] = $merged->all();
```

I get everything right when I'm doing my var_dump and I know how to access the data when I do a foreach. But that does not do what I want.

I would like to sort them (by `updated_at`) and have only three and not six.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried to make conditions like with the QueryBuilder on `$merge` but it does not work

```
$this->data['buildingsAndCircuits'] = $merged->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->limit(3)->all();
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've called `get` on each query then the query is executed and the result is returned. `orderBy` will not longer work after that since what you have in `$buildings, $circuits` and `$merged` is a collection.

You can however do this:

```
$buildings = Building::published()->limit(3)->get();
$circuits = Circuit::published()->limit(3)->get();

$merged = $buildings->merge($circuits)->sortByDesc('updated_at');

$this->data['buildingsAndCircuits'] = $merged->all();
```

Check what else you can do on collections in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods)